# SQL "WHERE IN" equivalent in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to extract all indices that have the value "US" and "JP" in column "Country"

Main_table

```
Date         Country   Customer_id
2019-01-01   UK        434393
2019-01-01   UK        553334
2019-01-01   US        424292
2019-01-01   JP        433535
```

Output table

Index:3,4

This is what I've tried so far, but I get zero results:

```
indexNames = df[ (df['Country'] == 'US') & (df['Country'] == 'JP') ].index
```

Comment: Right now you're looking for values where the country is equal to both "US" **and** "JP". Quite obviously, that can never happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change & to |

```
indexNames = df[ (df['Country'] == 'US') | (df['Country'] == 'JP') ].index
```

Or just `isin`

```
indexNames = df[ (df['Country'].isin(['US', 'JP']) ].index
```